# Group list by nested list and remove elements not corresponding to group

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Let's say I have such structure (but both `A` and `B` has a lot more properties):

```
class C
{
    List<A> A { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<B> B { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

And I would like to group by `B.GroupId` and also keep only those elements in each group that has corresponding `GroupId` value.

Here is an example data:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "A1",
        "B": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Name": "B1",
                "GroupId": 1
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Name": "B2",
                "GroupId": 1
            },
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Name": "B3",
                "GroupId": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "A2",
        "B": [
            {
                "Id": 4,
                "Name": "B4",
                "GroupId": 1
            },
            {
                "Id": 5,
                "Name": "B5",
                "GroupId": 2
            },
            {
                "Id": 6,
                "Name": "B6",
                "GroupId": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And as a resolut I would like to have 3 groups:

```
Group 1:
    [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "A1",
            "B": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Name": "B1",
                    "GroupId": 1
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "Name": "B2",
                    "GroupId": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "A2",
            "B": [
                {
                    "Id": 4,
                    "Name": "B4",
                    "GroupId": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

Group 2:
    [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "A1",
            "B": [
                {
                "Id": 3,
                "Name": "B3",
                "GroupId": 2
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "A2",
            "B": [
                {
                    "Id": 5,
                    "Name": "B5",
                    "GroupId": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

Group 3:
    [
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "A2",
            "B": [
                {
                    "Id": 6,
                    "Name": "B6",
                    "GroupId": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I have found that I can group by `B.GroupId` like this:

```
from a in c
from b in a.B
group a by b.GroupId
```

But how do I get rid of those elements whose `GroupId` is not in corresponding group? I tried removing them in `foreach` loop, but that removes them from all the groups not just one.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using Linq. Here is the example for 'GroupBy'

```
var jsonstring = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var objRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<A>>(jsonstring);
var result = objRoot.SelectMany(x => x.B)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupId)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToArray());
```

EDIT

```
var jsonstring = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var objRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<A>>(jsonstring);
var result = objRoot.SelectMany(AObj => AObj.B, (AObj, B) => new { AObj, B })
    .GroupBy(BObj => BObj.B.GroupId)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(y =>
                new A
                {
                    Id = y.AObj.Id,
                    Name = y.AObj.Name,
                    B = new List<B> { y.B }
                }).GroupBy(x => x.Id).ToList());
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

Comment: This returns just `List<B>` for each group. I need `List<A>` for each group.

Comment: So creating a new `A` object is the only way? I was hoping to avoid that as my real life `A` object has more that 100 properties, and most of them are complex (objects, lists etc).